# Modifying an existing emacs color theme

Tags: emacs

I like the Emacs color theme clarity. I start the theme with M-x color-theme-clarity. However, I would rather have the background was always black, rather than the mixed black and white as seen in my screenshot. It seems like if there is a line that has never had text on it, it will be white rather than black. How do I fix this?

Thank you and best regards.

[image: my emacs session]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is odd.  I also use the *clarity* color theme and I sometimes notice that if I switch to it from another theme some of the colors are off in certain areas.

Try setting it as the initial color theme in your .emacs file so that it is the first theme used when Emacs is opened:

```
(require 'color-theme)
(setq color-theme-is-global t)
(color-theme-clarity)
```

This might help if the issue is caused by a conflict with a previously used theme.

Comment: I think the variable color-theme-is-cumulative might have something to do with this.

Documentation:
*Determines wether new color themes are installed on top of each other.
If non-nil, installing a color theme will undo all settings made by
previous color themes.

Comment: Ha! A typo in the Emacs documentation: wether -> whether

Comment: Thanks Ray for the suggestion. And mmmasterluke thanks for the pointer to that variable. I need to look into color themes more. But, in the meantime Ray your code did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

This has been driving me crazy for a while, finally I think I have found the culprit.

It seems that it only happens when you have `custom-set-faces` settings in your .emacs configuration file. Try comment the settings to see if fixes the problem.

If the the problem is indeed caused by `custom-set-faces` you can simply set `:background "yourcolour" :foreground "yourcolour2"` of the `custom-set-faces` to fix it. `"youcolour" and "yourcolour2"` should be the colours used by your preferred theme.